# how to log in through social media and show the name, mail and photo in the navigation header?

Tags: android, facebook-login, google-signin

After successful login through Facebook/Google or any other social media login option, how can I show the user details like name, profile photo and email id in the navigation header?

Comment: Please add any code that you have tried to the question with an [edit].

Comment: it differs for each `social media`. You can see each social media's API documentation for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow `[Facebook Android Documentation](http://www.coders-hub.com/2014/07/how-to-add-facebook-sdk-in-android.html#.WNShqm-GO1s)  And Follow This [Facebook Login With Details Tutorial](http://www.coders-hub.com/2014/07/how-to-add-facebook-sdk-in-android.html#.WNShqm-GO1s)  You will get Your Results Hope this may Help you.!